# Determining Which Values a Sequence Converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Determine for which values of $x$ the sequence $\left(\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges.

Workings:

I have to consider multiple $x$.

$x = 0$:

$\left(\frac{0^n}{1+0^n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty} = \left(0\right)_{n=1}^{\infty} = (0, 0, 0, 0, ...)$

This is convergent.

$x = 1$:

$\left(\frac{1^n}{1+1^n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty} = \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, ... \right)$

This is convergent.

$x = -1$:

$\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{1+(-1)^n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty} = \left(\frac{-1}{0}, \frac{1}{2}, ...\right)$

This is not convergent.

Now I'm not to sure on what to do for values of $x$ where $x > 1$, $x < 1$, $0 < x < 1$ and $-1 < x < 0$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if $0 < x < 1 $ then it goes towards 0, too

Comment: I thought that converged to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x>1$ and $x<-1$, you can show that the $+1$ in the denominator becomes negligible as $n$ gets large.
$$\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x^n}} \stackrel{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 1.$$

You have already done the cases $x=\pm 1$.

For $-1<x<1$, you can take the limit directly by noting that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n = 0$.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{1+x^n} = \frac{\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n}{\lim_{n \to \infty} 1+x^n}=\frac{0}{1}=0.$$

Comment: Ok. I see. Thanks for the help. I thought I forgot how to determine when something is convergent but when you wrote your answer. It all started to come back. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your sequence as
$$
\frac{x^n}{x^n+1}=\frac{x^n+1-1}{x^n+1}= 1-\frac{1}{x^n+1}.
$$
This will simplify things a lot provided that you know well the sequence $x^n$.

Answer (score 1):

(a quick remark: the sequence is not defined for $x=-1$, as division by zero is not allowed)

If $x\in(-1,1)$, $x^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$ and $$\frac{x^n}{1+x^n} =\frac{x^n}{1+o(1)} \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} x^n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$$

If $|x| > 1$, $\lvert x^n\rvert\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty$ and $$\frac{x^n}{1+x^n} =\frac{x^n}{x^n+o(x^n)} \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \frac{x^n}{x^n} = 1$$

Comment: I meant to write that about $x = -1$, but I forgot. I see what you are doing, though your notation is different from what I am used to.

Comment: Oh -- the $o(\cdot)$ notation ([Landau notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)) is quite common in mathematics, and related to the (different) $O(\cdot)$, $\Omega(\cdot)$ and $\omega(\cdot)$ notations used in Computer Science. ($f=o(g)$ at a neighborhood of some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ means that there exists a function $\varepsilon$ with $\lim_{x\to x_0} \varepsilon(x) = 0$ such that $f(x)=\varepsilon(x)g(x)$)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification.